# Azure AD single sign on prompts for sign in and bssoNotSupported error in console

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

I have a web application that leverages the Azure AD SSO along with MSAL for the token acquisition. The user will be authenticated successfully when the user is signed-in to browser instance using the work account. However if the user is NOT signed-in then the user is prompted to sign in which is not the desired behavior. The below error message is logged in the browser console.

```
    BSSO Telemetry: {"result":"Error","error":"bssoNotSupported","type":"TBAuthTelemetry","data": 
    {"BSSO.info":"not-supported"},"traces":["BrowserSSO Initialized","window.navigator.msLaunchUri is 
   not available for _pullBrowserSsoCookie"]}
```

Any help deeply appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What are your users like? Are they cloud-only users or hybrid users? Why do you expect users to be signed-in without any prompt?

Comment: @juunas I implemented the SSO and hence the users are not supposed to prompt for the user name and password in domain linked machines

Comment: Hi @Sreejith.Vijayan are you still looking for any help?

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: Hi @ashraydimri Can you please raise a new SO question and mention the process you are following and the issue you are facing

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity Here is the thread for which I need help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348505/changing-the-domain-name-for-aad-auth-with-openidconnect-for-multi-node-multi-ge

Comment: @Sreejith.Vijayan Did you find a resolution for this?

Comment: It was due to the company's corporate policy I was getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar issue where the users were stuck at the login screen.
I added the tenant id in adaljs configuration and that error got resolved.